# Deploying to Azure App Service Linux - "dotnet: command not found"

Tags: asp.net, linux, azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I have created a new Linux App Service (Web App) on Azure. I have set the .NET version to 6. When I try to deploy via local Git I get the following error:

> deploy.sh: line 84: dotnet: command not found

If I change the version of .NET to 3.1, and check if .NET is installed via Kudu I can see that .NET is installed. However I can not use version 3.1 for my app.

How do I get a Linux App Service with .NET 6 installed correctly?

Comment: Have you checked the `site.config` file that should contain the `linuxFxVersion` to  'DOTNETCORE|6.0'

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT Where is `site.config` located?

Comment: Have you gone through this [github doc](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/blob/main/doc/hosts/appservice.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The project in question was using a [custom Kudu deploy script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) which ran during deployment fine when using a Windows App Service. However I would get the above error when it ran on Linux. Linux uses Oryx to perform the build, and I believe the Kudu custom script was running in place of the default Oryx script.

The solution for me was to **remove the custom script** so that the default Oryx deploy script ran. The Oryx script handled the installation of dotnet and the build and deploy succeeded.

Oryx allows a custom script post build which I may use to replace the extra build steps that I previously had in a Kudu script.